# SQL Server Management Studio 2005 SQL dump

Tags: sql-server, sql, ssms

How can i create a SQL dump (structure and data) with the Management Studio 2005 or the MS SQL server?

Comment: When you say 'dump' do you mean creating SQL statements that could be run to recreate the structure and data in a new db?>

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio right-click your database and select Tasks / Generate Scripts. Follow the wizard and you'll get a script that recreates the data structure in the correct order according to foreign keys. On the wizard step titled "Set Scripting Options" choose "Advanced" and modify the "Types of data to script" option to "Schema and data"